# Unexpected Error with Every Build

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise edition windows version. and it seems that for all my Xamarin.iOS projects out of nowhere every time I make a change on the code I receive this error without error code

> Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

If I cleaned the solution it get fixed but it's time consuming to clean and build with every tiny change

I'm made sure I all my Xamarin both Mac and Windows VS mac and windows and xCode all on the latest version. and tried uninstalling them and installing them again.

I run out of things to try here and I'm not sure what else to try

**UPDATE**
I found out this error in the output panel

> System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/B2C.iPhone/2c6cfc4a248b6131cfeb02b9ab72ef81/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/PreBuild/Accessibility.dll

Comment: You may file a bug as the error suggested.

Comment: @Kevin I did but god know when those are gonna be solved if ever, I was hoping someone would have been able t solve it